# How to fix Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VMWare randomly not detecting the internet connection when loading

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed on a virtual machine on VMware. When loading the VM, sometimes the connection icon that is normally found on the top right is totally gone and the internet stops working. The connection doesn't appear in the Connection setting. And the only way to fix the issue is to restart the VM.

This occurs totally at random and only when I load the VM. I have no problem on earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: Please edit your post to include more information about your setup. See a list of commands useful for network troubleshooting at the [Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en). It would be best create a pastebin for all the output and link to it in your question.

Comment: Running `lshw -C network` produces:
`*-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:50:56:26:2e:5a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation`

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04.1 on VMWare Fusion 10.1.3.  I was able to workaround the issue with the following steps:

1. Find the network device name from `ip link`, such as `ens33`
2. Manually set the device to the up state: `sudo ip link set ens33 up`
3. Click the drop-down in the top-right of the system bar, which show an entry for "Wired ..." and choose "Connect"

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to try;

1. [Ryan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080097/435043);
2. Boot off guest vm - I had an issue here regarding `.lck` files, and I just had to remove it after booting off.
3. Boot on guest vm - But network somehow is still off at here, and I think the next following will fix it.
4. Suspend guest vm
5. Resume guest vm

Thanks to [this vmware forum](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/No-networks-on-Ubuntu-guest-on-new-PC/m-p/2214648/highlight/true#M131557)